# How can I make a class change in WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and need to change the logo image to a full size one. I am unable to make this changes through custom css.

I need to change this:

```
<div class="navbar-brand left-align">
```

to:

```
<div class="navbar-brand center-align">
```

This is a WordPress page:

```
https://rpmhandicappinggiant.com/
```

header.php

```
div class="navbar-brand<?php if ( option::is_on( 'ad_head_select' ) ) { ?> left-align<?php } ?>"
```

I also tried changing this to center-align through FTP. It also did not work.

Comment: Most likely you'll need to find and change it in header.php

Comment: Is the condition here: `option::is_on( 'ad_head_select' )` pseudocode? or could you tell us what condition you are evaluating? it's mostly likely the reason it's not the class is not showing, the condition is not evaluating to true.